# Checkbox status without onclick or onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I get the status of a checkbox without having to call a function.

This is for a specific complex validation that my form needs.

I always want to keep listening to its status.

**Things I will need.**

- Its status when `checked`
- Status when `unchecked`

**I know this works**

```
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="showAddress3(this)" id="askAddress3">Call my friend to get the address

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function showAddress3() {
            if ($('#askAddress3').is(":checked")) {
                alert("Checkbox is checked.");
            } else if ($('#askAddress3').is(":not(:checked)")) {
                alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
            }
        }

    </script>
```

I Want to check its status without calling a function on it change event, something like

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="askAddress3">Call my friend to get the address

    <script type="text/javascript">

            if ($('#askAddress3').is(":checked")) {
                alert("Checkbox is checked.");
            } else if ($('#askAddress3').is(":not(:checked)")) {
                alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
            }


    </script>
```

This is only working when Page load, and does not work when I toggle it. Any suggestions or workarounds will be very helpful.

Comment: Just call `$('#askAddress3').is(":checked")` whenever you need to know the state... O.o

Comment: Event listeners are exactly for this situation, when you want to keep listening for an event. There is no better solution. If you don't want to have `onchange` attribute in your HTML you can add event listener in javascript but result will be the same.

Comment: There is no way to do that without a function. But for example, you could get that value when the users click the submit button, it won't be in "real time" but it will work because you're going to get the last value of the input (get it with input.value)

Comment: Try timeInterval function in JQuery.

Comment: Can someone help me implementing an event listener like @Walk suggested, there's no proper documentation out there for this.

Comment: @FayazAralikatti honestly, there's a lot of documentation about event listeners and answers below work fine for me (you can run those snippets and see that they do work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="askAddress3">Call my friend to get the address

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#askAddress3').on('change', function() {
    if ($('#askAddress3').is(":checked")) {
      alert("Checkbox is checked.");
    } else if ($('#askAddress3').is(":not(:checked)")) {
      alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @FayazAralikatti It's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

I thing the below is what you are looking for?

To trigger the change without hard coding `onchange=''` in the input tag?

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function() {
    if ($('#askAddress3').is(":checked")) {
        alert("Checkbox is checked.");
    } else if ($('#askAddress3').is(":not(:checked)")) {
        alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
    }
}) ;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="askAddress3">Call my friend to get the address
```

Comment: I don't think there is another way to get the checkbox status on toggle